# Java: addActionListener(); not working

Tags: java, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a launcher for a game, let's say PowerTown. But when i try to create a ActionListener for the button, it says non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context. How do I fix this?

```
package powertown;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PowerTown {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
    implements ActionListener; {
    //Start Varibles
    String path = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
    if (!new File(path + "PowerTownSave.txt").exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creating save file...");
        File f = new File(path + "PowerTownSave.txt");
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            try {
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path + "PowerTownSave.txt"));
                out.write("Coals \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("1 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Oils \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Bios \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Winds \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Sols \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Nukes \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Money \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("50 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Power \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Customers \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("5 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Storage \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("10 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("AvgUse \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("1 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Time \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Reputation \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Protests \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Coal Supply \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("800 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Coal Demand \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("30 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Oil Supply \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("100 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Oil Demand \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("9 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Bio Supply \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("7 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Bio Demand \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("3 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Nukes Supply \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("5 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Nukes Demand \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("3 \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Disaster probrobility \n");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("0");
                out.newLine();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to create save file, check your permisions. Are you admin? Are you root?");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create save file, check your permisions. Are you admin? Are you root?");
            return;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Save file found!");
    }
    System.out.println("Current readout of file will proceed, if file is empty, go to " + path + " , and then delete that file. After that, rerun the program.");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + "PowerTownSave.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String fileReadout = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(fileReadout);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    System.out.println("Startup save pickup has finished.");
    System.out.println("Attemptng to create a launch window... Please wait.");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PwrTwn Launcher");
    System.out.println("Created new frame!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    System.out.println("Set to terminate when closed...");
    JButton startButton = new JButton("Launch");
    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    System.out.println("Created new JButton!");
    startButton.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    startButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    System.out.println("Set alignment for JButton!");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
    System.out.println("Set Frame size!");
    startButton.setSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
    System.out.println("Set JButton size!");
    frame.getContentPane().add(startButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    System.out.println("Packaging...");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Launch window created!");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//some witty stuff goes here
    }
 }
```

Comment: Method NEVER EVER implements any Interface. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;`

```
public static void main(String[] args) implements ActionListener; {
```

Methods don't implement interface, class does. So fix it like:

```
public class PowerTown implements ActionListener {
```

---

```
startButton.addActionListener(this);
```

`this` can not be used in a `static` method. You are using this reference in the `main` method. Instead you can create the instance of the class and pass it. Like below.

```
PowerTown powerTown = new PowerTown();
startButton.addActionListener(powerTown);
```

Comment: Great! The first one worked! But it says PowerTown cannot be converted to ActionListener?

Comment: @BrianLuHappyville101 It should work. It is working for me and able to run it as well

Comment: @BrianLuHappyville101 You need to replace the existing lines with code lines I have provided here.

Comment: imported import java.awt.event.ActionListener; works!

Comment: I did work! Thanks! :D (does this count as an unnecessary comment?)

Comment: @BrianLuHappyville101 It is just an request to you as you are a new member to the site. You have privilege to accept the answer for your question. You can choose any answer which is best in your opinion and helped you. Hope to see you around.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to implement an `interface` on a method. This can't be done and doesn't make any sense (as a method can't contain other methods).

You must use a class as the base class for your `ActionListener`, eg:

```
class PowerTown implements ActionListener {
  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PowerTown listener = new PowerTown();
    startButton.addActionListener(listener);
  }
}
```

But this is a strange design, the best solution would be to extend directly `JFrame` and embed the behavior inside it:

```
class PowerTownFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  public PowerTownFrame() {
    JButton button = new JButton("test");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    ...
  }

  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PowerTownFrame frame = new PowerTownFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Redid the frame design, strange design because I'm one of the students at Java where he has an ambitious project but doesn't know how to do 99% of it. My view of learning these things is that it's more effective to go  on a journey and see for yourself than to have a teacher taking you on a set path. :D